# Organize Values in Dictionary alphabetically

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, dictionary

Hi guys I've been reading many post similar than the question I want to do but unfortunately any of them match with my issue. Actually I have dictionary used to populate a dropdownlist, since the values in the dictionary are not possible to organize alphabetically (there is not consistence, you'll see the values in the code below) how can I for example create an array or a list with an sequential number, order the values by this ID and then put the organized values into a new dictionary... or any other way. Appreciate your fast help.

This is my code actually:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDocumentTypes()
    {            

        Dictionary<string, string> docTypeList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //Values inserted manually for the moment
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F17- MyValue17");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F19- MyValue19");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F20- MyValue20");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F21- MyValue21");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F2- MyValue2");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F1- MyValue1");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F3- MyValue3");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F4- MyValue4");

        return docTypeList;
    }
```

//Here I try populate the dropdownlist with these values "ordered"

Dictionary doctypesource = GetDocumentTypes();

```
        var ordered = doctypesource.OrderBy(x => x.Value);

        DocumentType.DataSource = ordered;
        DocumentType.DataValueField = "Key";
        DocumentType.DataTextField = "Value";
        DocumentType.DataBind();
        DocumentType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem());
```

Finally when the dropdownlist is populated the values are not ordered but they are getting an order like this: F1- MyValue1, F17- MyValue17, F19- MyValue19, F2- MyValue2, F20- MyValue20, F21- MyValue21, F3- MyValue3, F4- MyValue4;

So I would like the order like this: F1- MyValue1, F2- MyValue2, F3- MyValue3, F4- MyValue4, F17- MyValue17, F19- MyValue19, F20- MyValue20, F21- MyValue21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are strings so they are sorted alphanumerically. Because of this, it's correct that "F17- MyValue17" would come before "F2- MyValue2" because the second character is a 1 in the first value and a 2 in the second value.

If you're able to pad your values with leading zeros the sorting would work. So for example you would use the following

```
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F17- MyValue17");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F19- MyValue19");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F20- MyValue20");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F21- MyValue21");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F02- MyValue02");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F01- MyValue01");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F03- MyValue03");
    docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F04- MyValue04");
```

If you can't do that, you will need to extract the numeric portion of the string to use for sorting. How you do it would depend on how you get these text values.

The following would work in your example code using the value format that you have

```
var ordered = docTypeList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(new string(x.Value.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsNumber(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsNumber).ToArray())));
```

Here's another possible solution that first sorts by the first part of the strings that's alpha and then sorts based on the first numeric portion, if there is one. Again, it works for the example values you provided in your comment but may not work for every value you would ever want to sort. For example, If you had "F1-A" and "F1-B", it would sort by the F, then by the 1, but it would ignore the rest of the string so B could come before A if it was found in the dictionary first.

```
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "C");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F17");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F1");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "B");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F2");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Z");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "F20");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "X");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "A");
        docTypeList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Y");

        var ordered = docTypeList.OrderBy(x => new string(x.Value.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()))
            .ThenBy(x => int.Parse(
                x.Value.Any(char.IsDigit) ? new string(x.Value.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray()) : "0"
                ));
```

Comment: Thanks +Marc, this can be a good way to solve it but, in the example above I only specified 'Fs' values but I also have values like "other element name1", "another element name2" etc, this solution will avoid items when start with a letter so the order will be bad again... This is correct or I'm wrong?

Comment: The solution was based on the values you provided and the way you were expecting the values to be sorted. If you are trying to sort "F17- MyValue17" with "F01- MyValue01" and with "other element name1" then what order would you expect the order to be? There needs to be some consistent format or rules to how the elements will be sorted.

Comment: The solution I suggested was to take the first number found in the string and use that to sort numerically. The number could be at the start of the string, in the middle of the string, or at the end. It just skips all non-numeric characters (if there are any) then grabs each numeric character till it gets to another non-numeric or the end of the string.

Comment: Yes Marc, as I said your solution is good and I also know your answer was based on my first xample, I'm simply asking what would happen wen I add all values I really have, I did not do mention of the rest because they are easily organized as they are strings without number such as "Aelement a", "Belement b", "Celement C" so on. What I'm doing is extracting the values starting with "F#" and adding a Zero when is single number like 01, 02, 03. This work fine although this is a hard way to do it. Thank you again.

Comment: The result list will look like: A, B, C, F, F01, F02, F17, F20, X, Y, Z. Assuming each letter or element separated by comma is a value in the list.

Comment: Just added another example that would work with those values. The more formats your text could be in the more complicated the sorting becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an IComparer to the OrderBy, considering that your numbers has 2 digits after F, below is the answer, you can make the proper modification for all your cases

```
class ComparerStrings : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        //Compare by numbers after your initial F
        return int.Parse(x.Substring(1, 2)).CompareTo(y.Substring(1, 2));
    }
}
```